# Как отличить между собой понятия "локация" и "ориентация"

Tags: значение-слов

Как различить между собой понятия "локация" и "ориентация"? В особенности вопрос касается случаев употребления этих понятий в быту, а не в узкоспециалтных контекстах. И ориентация, и локация есть определение местонахождения чего-либо (по-видимому, невозможного без определения своего собственного положения) по каким-либо признакам (ориентирам, сигналам). Можно ли сказать, локация - частный случай ориентации?

P. S. Может ли в смыслах этих слов (и в каких случаях) использоваться слово "навигация"?

Comment: "Отличить между собой" не говорят. Допустимо "**раз**личить между собой", но более употребительны выражения: "**от**личить одно **от** другого" и "различить одно и другое".

Answer (score 2):

Это слова *разного* значения и употребления. Есть смысл отметить также отличия *локации* и *ориентации* от похожих родственных им слов.

**Локация** - прежде всего технический термин, обозначающий *процесс* определения местоположения объекта техническими средствами. Наболее известна *радиолокация* (часто именуемая просто "локацией"), при которой по приходящему радиоимпульсу или последовательности таковых измеряют угловое направление на объект, его дальность и параметры движения.

**Локализация** - *результат* процесса любого поиска (нахождение искомого объекта, субъекта), в частном случае, *локации* объекта.  Другое значение слова - намеренное *ограничение в пространстве* какого-либо нежелательного явления (напр. очага возгорания при пожаре), взятие его под контроль.

**Дислокация** - собственно *местоположение*; используется как термин в военном деле.

В "локализованных" (переведённых на русский техническими специалистами, в меру знания языков) *компьютерных играх* слово **локация** является простой транслитерацией английского *location* (местоположение) и означает "*разновидность* местоположения" (бункер, лес, поле, военная база и т. п.).

**Ориентация** - положение объекта в пространстве относительно его условного центра (напр. геометрического), направленность его частей в системе координат. Может означать понимание собственного положения и направлений на известные объекты (есть выражение "потерять ориентацию").

**Ориентирование** - определение местоположения (напр., собственного) и нужного направления движения.

**Навигация** - процесс ориентирования, *организованный* (обычно для многих участников движения) при помощи сложных технических средств.

Comment: А может ли термин "дислокация" быть применён не в военном деле и обозначать местоположение, занятие определенного пространства каким-угодно предметом, существом? "Ориентация" в одном из смыслов направленность (уже определенное), а может ли она означать, подобно локации, определение направленности?

Comment: А может ли термин "дислокация" быть применён не в военном деле и обозначать местоположение, занятие определенного пространства каким-угодно предметом, существом? "Ориентация" в одном из смыслов направленность (уже определенное), а может ли она означать, подобно локации, определение направленности?

Comment: Может, но это будет звучать не совсем обычно, нестандартно. Как элемент разговорного красноречия или литературного стиля это слово понятно и в других контекстах.

Comment: Да, под "ориентацией" иногда понимают _процесс_ (=ориентирование), но не во всяком контексте это понятно, поэтому лучше выбирать более точное слово. Например, в понятии "спортивное ориентирование" _никогда_ не подменяют одно слово другим.

Comment: Ведь навигацией называется и определение и построение маршрута в приложении на телефоне...

Comment: Это один из _множества_ частных случаев "навигации" (до появления телефонов и прочих потребительских устройств навигация была преимущественно в пароходстве, авиации и космосе). Информация в телефоне получается и обновляется, в частности, от спутниковых систем, так что общее определение действует: это результат сложной организации сбора информации, в телефоне используются результаты её получения.

Answer (score 1):

Локация - это определение положения в пространстве какого-л. объекта по испускаемым или отражаемым им сигналам.

Различают звуковую локацию, оптическую локацию, биолокацию (чувство места у животных).

Слово "локация" обычно пользуются по отношению к животным (эхолокация у летучих мышей). Но фактически люди используют оптическую локацию.

Ориентация - это определение положения, обычно **используя логическое мышление** - главная разница. Это также умение разбираться в окружающей обстановке и обстоятельствах. Поэтому часто используется в отношении людей.

> Можно ли сказать, локация - частный случай ориентации?

Ориентация = локация + логическое мышление. Можно привести в пример потерявшегося в лесу человека, который, анализируя природу вокруг (полученную оптической локацией), пытается определить север/юг.

Comment: То есть локация - это умение выявить местоположение премета "в зоне досягамости". Оно включает пространство, охватываемое органами чувств или приборами. Верно? Например, локация заблудившегося в лесу человека - это понимание местоположения определенных деревьев вокруг, белок, грибов и т. д., а его ориентация - стремление по виденым ранее приметам (тем же деревьям и грибам) определить путь к выходу из него (к трассе, к опушке)?

Comment: Да, именно. Только локация больше направлена не на конкретный предмет, а на всё вокруг.

Comment: Ориентироваться - разбираться в расположении чего-либо, представляя своё местонахождение и умея найти дорогу (из словаря). Словари выдают синоним "ориентироваться" - "разобраться". Например: хорошо ориентироваться в лесу; слабо ориентироваться в политике.